AWS Lambda Node.js: "Cannot find module 'requires-port'" and other transient dependencies missing when using amqplib
I'm encountering an issue with my AWS Lambda function written in Node.js. The function uses the amqplib module to publish messages to RabbitMQ. When testing the Lambda, I get the following error:
Cannot find module 'requires-port'.
To work around this issue, I added the requires-port package explicitly to my package.json. However, after resolving this, a new error occurred:
Cannot find module 'url-parse'.
It seems like I need to manually add all transient dependencies, which clearly isn't the correct approach.
Here are some additional details:
The Lambda runs perfectly locally.
When packaged into a Docker container and deployed, it also works without issues.
I'm using lambda-zipper to generate the .zip file for deployment.
My project structure is as follows:
├── src
│   ├── common
│   ├── parsers
│   ├── services
│   ├── config.ts
│   ├── handler.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── package.json

Here is the relevant part of my package.json file (unnecessary details removed):
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "build:zip": "lambda-zipper build -f .env src node_modules -o dist/lambda.zip",
    "test": "mocha --recursive test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "amqplib": "^0.10.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lambda-zipper": "0.4.1",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  }
}

What I have observed:
The node_modules folder is included in the .zip file generated by lambda-zipper.
However, the Lambda still fails to find transient dependencies (requires-port, url-parse, etc.) when deployed to AWS.
What is the correct way to package a Lambda function to ensure all dependencies (including transitive ones) are available at runtime? Why does this issue occur, even though the node_modules folder is included in the .zip file?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Running the Lambda locally: works fine.
Packaging the Lambda in a Docker container: works fine.
Manually adding missing dependencies to package.json: temporarily fixes one issue, but introduces another.

